# Java XML String with attributes to NodeList (parsing)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodelist

I have a string, whose contents is an XML document.

Here is an example of a string.

```
String xmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + 
"<Service oem=\"myOem\" agent=\"myAgent\" version=\"0.5.5.0\" build=\"30-01-2014-11-46\" />";
```

I want to convert this string to a NodeList. A Google search led to this [article](http://itjbg.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/parse-xml-string-using-dom-and-stringreader-in-java/).

I tried the following code:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlContent));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList oNodeService = doc.getElementsByTagName("Service");
```

The problem is that I get a rip on the "db.parse(is)" line. The problem seems to be that this method does not support XML attrihutes.

The error message is:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:70: Element type "Service" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 70; Element type "Service" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at PkgNetAccelerator32.MainEvents.ShowHtsInfo(MainEvents.java:1575)
```

How can I successfully convert this XML string to a NodeList?

UPDATE:
Hmm, the failure is specific to the XML string. I gave a shortened version above. I removed all attributes that cause no crashes.

```
String xmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Service hostname=\"sarah-linux.localdomain\"uname=\"Linux sarah-linux.localdomain 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\" />";
```

If I were to hazard a guess, I would say it is the period or the dash. I wanted to get this update in first.

Comment: No, it really will support attributes. What error do you get?

Comment: The code you've given works for me. Please try to produce a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. My guess is that isn't your actual XML.

Comment: Same here. Just tested your code, verbatim.

Comment: Yes, it works in my side.

Comment: I can reproduce your error message by messing with the XML, adding a plain `\"` between attributes.

Comment: Please see my updated XML string above. Removing hostname or uname causes the parse to succeed, only when hostname and uname are both present does the failure occur.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between domain and uname: domain\"uname=

Comment: That is how the string comes to me, however the space is not the issue. I added a space and still crashes. The space is not relevant as the \" closes the previous attribute.

Comment: I added spaces everywhere and that did indeed solve the problem. I will have to let the vendor know. I saw that, but figured Java was smart enough to know that \" closes the previous attribute. Bad assumption.

Comment: Jonasnas, you should add the space as the answer, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String xmlContent = "<System><rpm-items><rtmap-items><Rule-list><name>RoutingPolicy3</name></Rule-list></rtmap-items></rpm-items></System>";
    InputStream isr = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(isr);

    NodeList ruleList = doc.getElementsByTagName("System");
```

Comment: Code-Only answers are not considered as good answers, please always try to add explanation as well - even if in summary